# Problema con PHP | Copyright automático

Tags: php, html, html5, aplicación-web, date

Tengo un problema con PHP, verán intento implementar un copyright automático pero PHP no hace nada, probablemente estoy haciendo algo mal a continuación pondré el código que utilizo para esta tarea:

```
&copy; 2016-<?php echo date("Y");?>
```

Ese es el script que utilizo.

Comment: ¿No aparece ningún tipo de mensaje? ¿Qué aparece si haces un echo de una cadena como 'hola'? ¿Qué servidor web usas y qué versión de php?

Comment: Hola Shaz,

Acabo de quitar date por un echo "hola", y no aparece nada
Estoy utilizando el paquete Wamp en Windows 10:
Apache: 2.4.2
PHP: 5.4.3

Comment: Sé que va a sonar a perogrullada, pero... ¿qué extensión tiene el fichero? Si tiene extensión .html no se mostrará nada (aunque se verá el código PHP si le das a ver código fuente)

Comment: Hola Alvaro, la extensión es html tienes razón verifique y el código php se ve desde el código fuente, ¿solamente funciona si es extensión: .php?

Comment: PROBLEMA RESUELTO, cambie la extensión .html por .php fue un error de novato, gracias por sus respuestas!

Comment: Así es, todo los HTML que lleven aunque sea una línea de código PHP deben de ponerse esa extensión.

Comment: @gburu98 Sí, el motor de PHP no procesa el fichero y el código se muestra como texto si la extensión no es `.php`. Me alegra que mi comentario te ayudara. Añade lo que hiciste como respuesta y acéptala. Así si otra persona se encuentra con el mismo problema en el futuro, podrá ver cuál es la solución

Comment: Nuevamente gracias Alvaro, por tu comentario cambie la extensión y funciono, ahora mismo agregare la solución!!

Answer (score 2):

Si estas usando php en un archivo con formato .html, puedes usar una regla de htaccess para que tu codigo php sea legible en un archivo .html es tan sencillo como agregar una simple linea en tu htaccess pero tambien depende de si tu servidor permite usar htaccess, pero bueno te dejo esta line para tu htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por esta valiosa información!!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUCIÓN:**

Cambiar extensión (.html), por la extensión nativa de PHP (.php), esto es valido cuando agregas código php dentro de html.